# Functioning of a continuous data stream processing neural network?

Tags: continuous-signals, neural-network

I've been searching with unfortunately no relevant results about something I have trouble to figure out: neural networks which process continuous data stream (audio, video, anything with a state depending of a period of time)

I'd like a simple explanation on how this kind of NN (which I couldn't find the name, perhaps it's CNN but I am not sure) works.

Currently I only know "basical" NN you're introduced to when you're starting with machine learning — those taking many inputs from an image for example (so these inputs are pixels here), getting fed with a lot of relevant images of different categories and telling you which category the image you provide it belongs to.

These basical NN relies on **steady** information, they don't change over time, so I can figure out how they can be processed. 
But it's harder for me to understand how continuous data can be processed; in a vocal removing sound processer for instance, how does it "know" what data to put next ? How is it even trained as the inputs are not general but relying on time ?

Comment: Definitely want to read Tim O'Shea on that. ["Google Scholar"](https://scholar.google.de/citations?user=4S4GyXYAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao) him, look for his most-cited papers, pick the topmost NN one.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Will check that, thank you !

Comment: I think that the way this question is phrased makes it too open. There are many different ways by which you can approach "state updates from real time data" depending on what you are trying to do. A basic neural network is still based on a digital delay line, see first figure [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261481262_A_vacuum-tube_guitar_amplifier_model_using_a_recurrent_neural_network) for example.